# Create web server writable folder phpMyAdmin config file

Tags: phpmyadmin

I received this problem:

Please create web server writable folder config in phpMyAdmin top level directory as described in documentation. Otherwise you will be only able to download or display it.

What can I do to solve this problem. My phpMyAdmin version is 3.5.8.2

Comment: have you tried setting the folder permissions for write? You'll probably need to do it by the numbers.

Comment: Have you tried following the documentation? Something like [this setup guide](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#using-setup-script), perhaps?

Answer (score 3):

Go to your phpMyAdmin folder, typically `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin` for more recent versions.

Create a folder called `config`:

```
cd /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
mkdir config                        # create directory for saving
chmod o+rw config                   # give it world writable permissions - this will be removed once your configuration has been saved on the server [as this directory is required by the application to be removed as a security measure]
```

Once you have generated your configuration, you may copy it from the `config` folder `/usr/share/phpMyAdmin/config.inc.php` to your installation folder, or for Redhat flavors, your `/etc/phpMyAdmin` folder.

A little late, but its the thought that counts.

- FYI - all this information is available in the phpMyAdmin documentation

Comment: How to do it on Mac OS ?

Answer (score 2):

A long while after the original question was asked, but I had the same problem.

On my Ubuntu 14.04 server, the file you need to make writeable is located in `/var/lib/phpmyadmin`.  `config.inc.php` is owned by `root:www-data`, so setting group write flag fixed it: `660`.

I figured this out by modifying the code in `\usr\share\phpmyadmin\setup\frames\index.inc.php` (line 48) where phpMyAdmin performs the check and reports the error.  I made the error print the file path:

```
check_config_rw($config_readable, $config_writable, $config_exists);
if (!$config_writable || !$config_readable) {
    $file_path = ConfigFile::getInstance()->getFilePath();
    messages_set(
        'error', 'config_rw', __('Cannot load or save configuration to '.$file_path),
        PMA_lang(__('Please create web server writable folder [em]config[/em] in phpMyAdmin top level directory as described in [doc@setup_script]documentation[/doc]. Otherwise you will be only able to download or display it.'))
    );
}
```

Comment: Regarding the permission issue this is from the [PMA setup script](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html#using-setup-script): Debian and Ubuntu have simplified this setup and all you need to do is to execute `/usr/sbin/pma-configure` and after you are done `/usr/sbin/pma-secure`.

Answer (score -1):

It's not a big problem if you cannot create a writable folder "config" in phpMyAdmin's folder. You'll be able to download the created configuration to a file, but you must be able to put this downloaded config.inc.php back to the phpMyAdmin's folder.